# Slider loop with backgroud image

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, slider, setinterval

I have a container and within it 5 (or more) items (divs) with another 2 child divs, the second (child) div has a background image (declared as inline-style "background" property). Now, I want an infinite cycle/loop of all this images (items with backgroud images) to work, after one iteration the first one become second, second third... fifth become first etc, with some interval.

I was trying some javascript and jquery with no success, is there a way how to do that? Thank you so much for help.

The code is:

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .container {
          position: relative;
          width: 100%;
          display: -webkit-box;
          display: flex;
        }
        .container .img {
          position: relative;
          width: 240px;
          height: 240px;
        }
        .container .img div {
          position: relative;
          background-size: cover;
          background-position: center;
          width: 240px;
          height: 240px;
          opacity: 0.9;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
        .container .img div:hover {
          opacity: 1;
        }
    </style>
    
    <div id="s" class="container">
        <div class="img">
            <div style="background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/271/240)"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="img">
            <div style="background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/221/240)"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="img">
            <div style="background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/101/240)"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="img">
            <div style="background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/22/240)"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="img">
            <div style="background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/11/240)"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setInterval(function(){ 
$i=$(document).find('.container .img:nth-child(1)'); 
$i.clone().appendTo( ".container" );
$i.remove()}, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very simple and it is working good (with jQuery).